# How to enable site.pp in Puppet server？

Tags: puppet

It displays:

> Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: `/etc/puppet/manifests/test.pp`

When I sent a file from server to client in puppet 3.8.4. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add code snippets to the question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Hi. This question is quite unspecific. It appears that you do not have a general understanding of the Puppet tool chain yet. I suggest you try the [training course](https://puppetlabs.com/download-learning-vm) before you go ahead and build your own setup.